# Understanding uint32_t char typecast (Bytes)

Tags: c, casting, char, uint32-t

Lets say we have this:

```
int main()
{

    int32_t* value = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint32_t array[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    *value = *(uint32_t*)((char*)array + 8);

    printf("Value is: %d\n", *value);

    return 0;
}
```

The value in this case would be 3.
Why exactly is that?
If we cast an uint32_t to char, does that mean one char is 4 Byte in uint32_t and therefore

```
array[9] = {0, 4, !!8!!, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32};
```

Could someone try to explain this?

Comment: `int32_t* value = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));` Why casting it this way?

Comment: Why are you writing some obfuscated code and then asking why it is doing such and such?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I get 3.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I am not sure, but I think the OP is getting 3 too...

Comment: Well it's actually a task for school and they've used malloc to allocate space and there was another task that asked what is the problem. Well the code in the task doesn't free memory but that's not the point.

Yes I'm getting 3 too, but why exactly is it 3?

Comment: The problem is that the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: It's just a snippet and it's not really what im on about. You can see below what I actually intended :D

Comment: @4386427 Where is the UB? It looks fishy, yes, but I can't see UB. Well, except using `%d` for `int32_t`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah, I mis-understood.  I saw the `!!8!!` in the third position of `array[9]` thinking it meant they were getting 8 instead of 3.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Casting as char pointer to a uint32_t pointer changing memory pointed to by an int32_t pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: @4386427 The aliasing here is happening only between `char` and `uint32_t`. `int32_t` is only assigned by value from `uint32_t`, which is OK.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Due to compatibility the assignment itself is ok but not the casting

Comment: @4386427 What is wrong with the casting? The `uint32_t` `array`  is casted to `char*` and then back to `uint32_t*`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Consider a system where a char isn't 1 byte

Comment: @EugeneSh. Quote: "The uint32_t array is casted to char* and then back to uint32_t*" Well, there is one step missing... The uint32_t array is casted to char* **and modified** and then back to uint32_t*

Comment: @4386427 I think this is implementation defined at most... The object itself is not modified.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well - okay - let's leave it there to avoid extended discussion in comments. I'm sure it's UB. You're sure it isn't. Fine - we can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize an array, each initializer sets an element of the array regardless of how many bytes each element takes up.

You machine is probably using little-endian byte ordering.  That means that `array` looks like this in memory:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------

|      [0]      |      [1]      |      [2]      |      [3]      | ...
```

Each value of type `uint32_t` is 4 bytes long with the least significant byte first.

When you do `(char*)array` that casts `array` (converted to a pointer) to a `char *`, so any pointer arithmetic on a `char *` increases the address by the size of a `char`, which is 1.

So `(char*)array + 8` points here:

```
(char*)array + 8 ------------------
                                  v
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------

|      [0]      |      [1]      |      [2]      |      [3]      | ...
```

That pointer is then converted to a `uint32_t *` and dereferenced, so it reads the value 3.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Probable memory layout]

You created `array[9]` takes 36 bytes. It stores in memory as shown in first row. `3` store as I represented(It varies from compiler).

After you typecast it into char memory is seen as shown in 2nd row.

Now if you add 8 it will go to 8th position that  mean after `02`, why because, `(char*)array + 8` treated as `type+8`. Here `type` is `char`. So it moves only 8 bytes.

Then memory from 8 to 35 type cased to uint32_t and first value stored in `*value`. So it will `3` only.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!